# Combine top-level reducer with slice reducers, for RTK.configureStore

Tags: redux-toolkit

How can combine **top-level reducer code** with the aggregate reducer from `combineReducers`?

I have defined several store slices. `combineReducers` allows creating a single reducer, by mapping a name to each slice's reducer:

```js
import { slice as fooSlice } from './foo/slices.js'
import { slice as barSlice } from './bar/slices.js'

export const store = RTK.configureStore({
    reducer: {
        foo: fooSlice.reducer,
        bar: barSlice.reducer,
    },
})
```

Each of those reducers can, by design of `createSlice`, only access their own subset of the state.

Then, I need some top-level reducer code as well. For example, a “save to persistent storage” action:

```js
import {
    persistenceActions,
    saveWorldState,
} from './persistence.js'


function globalStoreReducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        [persistenceActions.save]: {
            saveWorldState(state)
        },
    default:
        // FIXME: How to delegate to the slice reducers?
        return reducer(state, action)
    }
    return state
}
```

The goal is to have a single reducer function that combines not only all the slice reducers, but also the top-level reducer with access to the entire store. Then, use that for `RTK.configureStore`:

```js
export const store = RTK.configureStore({
    reducer: globalStoreReducer,
})
```

How can I properly **combine the directly-implemented reducer code with the combined reducer**, for use as the single reducer in `RTK.configureStore`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do a

```js
const allMySliceReducersReducer = combineReducers({
        foo: fooSlice.reducer,
        bar: barSlice.reducer,
    })
```

and call that from your `globalStoreReducer`.

But that said, `saveWorldState` sounds like a side effect, and those are never allowed in reducers.